# Windows XP content rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, rendering, windows-xp

I have an application made in .NET 4.5 made for newer PC's, but now I got a Windows XP clients: / so I gotta revert, I successfully reverted to .net 4 for Windows XP, everything works perfectly on Windows 7 > Windows 10. But there is some serious content rendering problems I encountered in Windows XP, now before I asked here, I searched Google and here to find a solution. But no luck so far. This is the problem, 
I have MainWindow and Window1 (example), main window contains some red-background label, button and a contentcontrol (currently null so its invisible), and on button click, I have this line:

```
this.contentControl.Content = new Window1().Content;
```

Window 1 background is set to red color, so its just changes the background, which works on my machine (windows 10) but the same app crashes on win xp, look at the pictures. Any ideas? (my whole application is made to change windows using .Content so I must somehow fix the drawing of chaging content, any ideas what to try out? ).

[image: windows 10 before button clicked]

[image: windows 10 after button clicked]

[image: Windows XP before button clicked]

[image: Windows XP after button clicked]

Update: I'm sorry I didn't included the exception:

```
Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
```

.
[image]

After edit:
this is on button click:

```
this.contentControl.Content = new UserControl1().Content;
```

and xaml of usercontrol:
[image]

bonus question ::
since my application is quite big, and everywhere i used window, now i have to switch to user control for this methods to work ... since if i switch

```
this.contentControl.Content = new UserControl() { Background = Brushes.Green };
```

to

```
this.contentControl.Content = new Window() { Background = Brushes.Green };
```

again it pops up exception ... any way to fix this... if there is not .. i will change the windows to user controls no problem...

[image]

and one big thanks to sir "mm8" for fixing my problem :))

Comment: Do your clients have good reason for not upgrading from XP? The OS is a dinosaur, and support has been pulled.

Comment: trust me i said that .. but they say they have too many computers using XP right now ... so its like im forced .. we are installing the software on many computers .. not only one .. so im kinda forced ... even tho i didnt like it .. but ...

Comment: So im clear, Window1 litterally "fills" MainWindow when it is called?

Comment: yes, as you can see, the same code-line works on win10 but not on xp .. .. if i put on try catch, i get an exception which i have written on the bottom of the question.

Comment: .Content = new Window1().Content seems so fishy to me....you are using wpf not winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the Content of Window1 to a UserControl:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window8" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 />
</Grid>
```

You can then simply create an instance of this UserControl and set the Content property of the ContentPresenter in your MainWindow to this one:

```
this.contentControl.Content = new UserControl1();
```

Comment: just tried this, works on win 10, it throws the same exception on win xp.

Comment: How does the XAML markup and code for UserControl1 look like then?

Comment: i edited the question, there is a new pic, btw i dont have any code in usercontrol1 except for the default (initialize component..)

Comment: Try to remove .Content as per my answer. You should set the contentControl.Content property to an instance of the UC and not to its Content.

Comment: oops yes you're right, if i shourtly do this, on button click:
this.contentControl.Content = new UserControl() { Background = Brushes.Green };
works on both OS's ... ok i will mark this as solved, and i will post a picture for a bonus question..

Comment: Regarding your "bonus" question; You cannot set the Content property of a ContentControl to an instance of a window since a window must be the root of the visual tree so this won't work on Windows 10 either. So you should stick to using a UserControl as per my answer.

Comment: yeah, thats actaully what the exception is saying .. ok not big deal.. will change the needed windows to user controls anyway .. thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should be using a `ContentPresenter` for.

Update your MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"/>
        <Label Content="yoooooo"/>
        <Button Height="50" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Click-event / code-behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newControlContent = new ContentControl
    {
        Content = new UserControl1()
    };
    ContentPresenter.Content = newControlContent;
}
```

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication9.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="PaleVioletRed">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: yeah this works, the first answer works the same way, except i didnt used it properly.., what exactly is the difference between contentControl and content presenter ? any ideas why should i switch to it ?

Comment: The ContentControl is used for controls that display 'content', and a ContentPresenter is used to display the content of 'controls'. In my opinion, it's a bit cleaner to have a ContentPresenter, and then update the ContentPresenter with dynamic data, as it's more obvious and clear what is going on.